# Resizing a excel pasted object in powerpoint with vba

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I've cobbled together a VBA script (I'm no expert, but thanks to the kind folks around here, I've been able to get something together and mostly working) to copy from multiple excel sheets into a powerpoint file (used a template, as you will see from the code.

```
Sub ATestPPTReport()

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim PPShape As PowerPoint.Shape

Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

''define input Powerpoint template
    Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
''# Change "strPresPath" with full path of the Powerpoint template
    strPresPath = "C:\template.ppt"
''# Change "strNewPresPath" to where you want to save the new Presentation to be created
    strNewPresPath = "C:\macro_output-" & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & ".ppt"
    Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
    PPPres.Application.Activate


PPApp.Visible = True
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''define destination slide
    SlideNum = 1
    PPPres.Slides(SlideNum).Select
    Set PPShape = PPPres.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("slide1box")
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

''define source sheet
    Sheets("Info1").Activate
'copy/paste from
    XLApp.Range("Info1Block").Copy
    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''define destination slide
    SlideNum = 2
    PPPres.Slides(SlideNum).Select
'    Set PPShape = PPPres.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("slide2box")
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

''define source sheet
    Sheets("Info2").Activate
'copy/paste from
    XLApp.Range("Info2Block").Copy
    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Close presentation
    PPPres.SaveAs strNewPresPath
    'PPPres.Close
    'Quit PowerPoint
'PPApp.Quit
'    MsgBox "Presentation Created", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

My problem is: how do I resize/reposition the object once it's been pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function "PasteSpecial" returns a shape object, which you can use to resize or reposition.

For example:

```
Dim ppShape as PowerPoint.Shape
set ppShape = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse)
```

Then you can use this shape object to resize it. For example:

```
ppShape.Height = xyz
ppShape.Top = abc
```

etc etc.

Hope this helps.
Vikas B

Comment: Thanks for the help, and this is very likely my own inexperience, but it returns a runtime 13 error (type mismatch) with the
    set ppShape = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoFalse)
line. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you confirm if you declare your variable as *Dim ppShape as PowerPoint.Shape* and not as Dim ppShape as Shape? If it still gives the error, try to declare the variable as Dim ppShape as Object to avoid the type mismatch error.

Comment: Vikas! Thanks so much! I changed dim ppShape to an object and i was able to get it to work! Many thanks!

Comment: FWIW, while defining the var as an object works, you lose the benefit of intellisense, and really, it's just papering over the basic problem which is that PasteSpecial returns a ShapeRange, not a Shape, hence the Type Mismatch error.  Use .PasteSpecial(parameters)(1) instead.  That returns the first item in the newly pasted shaperange, which will be a single shape; no error, and you can work with the shape AS a shape.

Answer (score 0):

This has been working for me:

```
Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(x).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
shp.Left = topLeft + 1
shp.Top = midTop + 1
shp.Width = midLeft - topLeft - 1
```

Note the variables are set locally to place the image where I want it in relation to the slide.  You can easily replace with integers.

It also works for DataType:=10 items as well